# Renaming Image Content In Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I have loaded some Images into my program and now I would like to change the names of those images, they are in the content folder under a sub folder. Do I just right click and press rename or is there a better way to do this without breaking any code. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the file-name of these images? Or do you want to change the name of them in the code?

Comment: I want to change the file name of the images but was wondering by doing this will it update the code?

Comment: How about renaming before importing?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the files you would need to change the references of the file as well. It will unfortunately not get updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @user443 - If the answer helps you could you please mark it as an answer